# play console: should I roll out internal test for in-app purchases?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, in-app-purchase, google-play-console

I want to test in-app purchasing for the first time. I uploaded the APK and rolled out internal test track. It takes for 7 days and more to pass pending state. Then, I should edit the code and update the app for 10 more times (each one 7 days pending? it is hard to believe).

Is there any way to test the in-app purchases without rolling out? Without in-app purchases, we can test the app with android studio as many times as we can. But for in-app purchases it takes forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is play console chat response after several communications:

> Unfortunately you have to technically. publish the app for review for any track

So, we can't even test in-app purchases or subscription purchases in google. There is no way to do that in a time-efficient way. You have to wait for 7 days and more for each simple change of the code.